# My MacBook 2012 has sleep/wake problems with SSDs as internal drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sleep-wake

Whenever I have an SSD (crucial mx100 or samsung 850) as my internal hard drive, my macbook has problems with sleep/wake. If I unplug my macbook and let it sleep, the hard drive does not wake up. It will work for about a second then it'll freeze for a few seconds and quickly flash a white screen and reboot. This also happens when I close the laptop while it's plugged in and I try to reopen it. Sometimes it will happen randomly after a few hours of using the computer (and possibly letting it sleep in-between).

Some solutions I tried:

1. Reseting SMC
2. Installing OS X via USB and installing it as internal hard drive
3. Reinstalling OS X
4. Repairing the drive in Disk Utility

Solutions that worked at first (for a few days), but eventually failed:

1. Replacing the hard drive cable. (No problems for about a month)
2. Preventing the drive from going to sleep in settings

I can boot the SSD from a USB enclosure perfectly fine. When I have the SSD as my internal drive, I sometimes get the prohibitory sign and the file system will appear corrupted. But the minute I put the SSD in a USB enclosure, everything works perfectly again.

What is going on? Anyone know?

Also, I have high data error counts in DriveDx with the SSDs, however the stock hard drive works perfectly fine as my internal drive.

Comment: UPDATE: After reinstalling the stock hard drive and having success for a day. I am now experiencing the same problem with the stock hard drive.

Comment: Also, my magsafe light is sometimes dim. Is it possibly a power issue?